# How to run test projects in orchard cms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I have been trying to run my own test method in orchard cms , but visual studio does not detect test projects in the solution.is there any specific method to run tests in orchard?or this is a problem with visual studio itself not detecting the test classes.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orchard uses NUnit tests, so you should install NUnit in your Visual Studio to be able to run the tests.